# How to find out what autostarted a program?

Tags: autostart

There is lots of advice on **how** to make a program autostart, but the thing I need now is the opposite of that: I want to find out **why** a certain program starts on boot.

The use case is as follows: After some messing around with `xbindkeys`  I decided to shut down Ubuntu, take a snapshot of the VM, and then make `xbindkeys` autostart. However, `xbindkeys` was running already after the boot. How do I find out why?

Tried `systemctl`, looked into `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile`. Not there. `pstree` says `xbindkeys` descends directly from `systemd`.

Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

Comment: Hi.. your main question seems to be why xbinkeys auto starting? if yes the answer is easy to explain..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you install the package `xbindkeys`

`sudo apt install xbindkeys`

it creates a .desktop file in your users home directory in `$HOME/.config/autostart/` with below contents

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=xbindkeys
Comment=Start xbindkeys
Exec=xbindkeys_autostart
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=
GenericName=
Hidden=true
```

If you observe the `Exec` line.. this .desktop file will execute `xbindkeys_autostart` which is actually `/usr/bin/xbindkeys_autostart` with below contents

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
set -u
set -E

PROG="/usr/bin/xbindkeys"
NOAUTO="${HOME}/.xbindkeys.noauto"

# This file autostarts xbindkeysrc if the user (or system) has a config
# for it AND does NOT Have a .xbindkeys.noauto in his homedir.

# we only run if there is no NOAUTO file
if ! [[ -f ${NOAUTO} ]] && [[ -x ${PROG} ]]; then
    # User config wins over system config
    # guile config wins over classic config
    for cfile in "/etc/xbindkeysrc" "$HOME/.xbindkeysrc" "$HOME/.xbindkeysrc.scm"; do
        if [[ -f ${cfile} ]] || [[ -L ${cfile} ]]; then
            CONF="${cfile}"
        fi
    done

    # Run $PROG - if it has been configured
    if [ -n "${CONF}" ]; then
        $PROG -f $CONF
    fi
fi
```

for example manually added autostart programmes with directly entering commands in startup application list is like below

[image]

you can see the difference between both of these .desktop files for the line "Hidden" which is false for one and true for other

[image]

[image]

if you make the `Hidden=true` to `Hidden=false` you can see it in GUI startupapplications list like below

[image]

Comment: In my case it seems to be `/etc/xdg/autostart/`, not `$HOME/.config/autostart/`. The rest of your answer stands. Still curious about the general algorithm for such things, though.

Comment: etc xdg for all users......... `.config` for user..

Comment: i still doubt why it went to /etc/xdg/ in your case.. may be manual entry? if possible purge xbindkeys and then install xbindkeys.. and see if it is still created in /etc/xdg